# How to avoid implementation of a wrong domain concept

Tags: software-design

We have the following concept in our application (composed of a UI and a REST backend):

`Container` is-a-parent-of `lineItem`s

a `lineItem` cannot be created without having a valid `Container` and both of these entities are persisted in DB via spring data.

The UI lists the `lineItem`s in two pages

- list view: the `lineItem`s of a single `Container` are displayed
- search page: the `lineItem`s of different `Container`s are displayed

We have a single source of data for both of these UI pages. The data comes from a common REST backend which returns a list of `lineItem`s wrapped in a POJOview object (along with other information) - current state.

Change needed - On the search page, now, we need to show some information from the `Container` of a `lineItem`. So, now we need to make available the data of a `Container` associated with a `lineItem` on the search page. We are currently discussing two possible approaches for doing it:

Approach 1: 
`POJOview {
List<LineItem>
List<Container>
}`

- This approach avoids implementation of a wrong concept(described below) which gets implemented in approach 2.
- `List<LineItem>` and `List<Container>` are sent separately, so, less data gets transferred to the UI. If 20 `lineItem`s belonging to 1 `Container` are sent, then there is only one object of the `Container` as compared to 20 Objects of `Container` in approach 2.
- The code is easier to understand and maintain
- A disadvantage is that it requires some extra logic in the search page for the UI to map the `lineItem` to its `Container` in the other list

Approach 2:
`POJOview {
List<LineItem> //insert Container of a lineItem as a member variable in the lineItem itself. Container instance is annotated with @Transient to avoid persistence in DB.
}`

- This approach implements a wrong concept in the backend in the sense that `lineItem` now contains the `Container` which is opposite of the domain concept (`Container` is-a-parent-of `lineItem`s) and hence it is not intuitive and makes the code difficult to understand and maintain.
- Each `lineItem` now contains `Container`, so, if we have 20 `lineItem`s on the page belonging to the same `Container`, then the `Container` data which is now a part of `lineItem` gets loaded 20 times (performance hit)
- This has an advantage of a quick fix

The problem is that despite all these facts, my colleague still maintains that Approach 2 is the optimal way since it is a quick fix and he sees nothing wrong in it. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my opinion, one of the good ways to implement would be as below:

The REST service can return data in following format:

a) A list of LineItem objects where each LineItem object contains just the ID of its container (note: it is not a wrong approach because the child objects can very well contain the reference to its parent as long as the parent data is not repeated in every child). 
b) A list of container objects. Obviously only those containers should be returned that are referenced by the line items.

The front end logic can go over the list of line items and look up the container details in the container list.

The data items a) and b) can be sent via separate calls or a single call. Ideally if the REST principles are to be followed strictly and making two calls is not impacting performance, then two separate calls should be made and thus as per the REST principles  LineItem Resource is retrieved in one call and Container Resource in another call.

By using this approach, the container information is not repeated, only the container IDs are repeated in the line item objects which should be okay in most cases.

Thus this approach is essentially similar to Approach 1) that you have described except for the fact that lineitems can contain the ID of their parents (container).

As per what I understand, Approach 2 mentioned in the question repeats the full container information for each lineitem object which is definitely wrong. Ids can be repeated but not the full object whether the data is being retrieved from DB or being passed around in the backend or is being sent to front end.

Hope this provides some clarity.

Comment: Thanks @punitoza. I forgot to specify that the lineItem objects contains a reference to thier respective Container, so, I am in agreement with what you said.